# css float block question

Tags: css

Hi current I have something like this:

```
<div class = "blah">
I
<div class = "car"> am </div>
<div class = "dog"> bob </div>
</div>
```

where I have

```
car: float:left, display:block
dog: float:left, display:block
```

and it comes out in this order:

```
am bob I
```

I want it to show:

```
I am bob
```

How can I do it by just changing the css?

Comment: why aren't you using `span`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.car{ display:inline;}
.dog{ display:inline;}
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

```
.blah {float:left, display:block}
```